# Randomly selection of number from list of integers which is proportional to its magnitude

Tags: python, random

Select a number randomly with probability proportional to its magnitude from the given array of n elements
consider an experiment, selecting an element from the list A randomly with probability proportional to its magnitude.
assume we are doing the same experiment for 100 times with replacement, in each experiment you will print a number that is selected randomly from A.

Ex 1: A = [0 5 27 6 13 28 100 45 10 79]
let f(x) denote the number of times x getting selected in 100 experiments.
f(100) > f(79) > f(45) > f(28) > f(27) > f(13) > f(10) > f(6) > f(5) > f(0)

```
def pick_a_number_from_list(A):
    sum=0
    cum_sum=[]
    for i in range(len(A)):
        sum = sum + A[i]
        cum_sum.append(sum)
    #print(cum_sum)           
    r = random.uniform(0,sum)
    number=0
    for index,i in enumerate(cum_sum):
        if(r>=cum_sum[index] and r<cum_sum[index+1]):
            return A[index]
    return number

def sampling_based_on_magnitued():
    A = [0,5,27,6,13,28,100,45,10,79]
    for i in range(1,100):
        number = pick_a_number_from_list(A)
        print(number)

sampling_based_on_magnitued()
```

I have written the above code but not getting the correct output.

Comment: **I have written the above code but not getting the correct output.Could someone please help me to understand where i am doing wrong.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: as per the problem it should return the 100 from the list max number of time and 0 min number of times but the code is not returning the output expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a logical error you made. When you are checking for range
`r>=cum_sum[index] and r<cum_sum[index+1]`, you are actually using the number `A[index+1]` and not `A[index]`.

```
import random

def pick_a_number_from_list(A):
    sum=0
    cum_sum=[]
    for i in range(len(A)):
        sum = sum + A[i]
        cum_sum.append(sum)
    #print(cum_sum) 
    r = int(random.uniform(0,sum))
    print(r)
    number=0
    for index in range(len(cum_sum)):
        if(r>=cum_sum[index] and r<cum_sum[index+1]):
            return A[index+1]
    return number

def sampling_based_on_magnitued():
    A = [0,5,27,6,13,28,100,45,10,79]
    a = dict()
    #A.sort()
    print(A,sum(A))
    for i in range(1,100):
        number = pick_a_number_from_list(A)
        #print(number)
        if number not in a:
            a[number] = 1
        else:
            a[number]+=1
    print(a)

sampling_based_on_magnitued()
```

This is the final frequencies of selection I got on my machine

```
{100: 35, 5: 1, 45: 15, 79: 20, 28: 8, 13: 8, 6: 2, 27: 9, 10: 1}
```

Comment: where exactly you have made the changes?

Comment: Hi Raj,
it is always not giving correct output sometime small number printed more time than higher number.

Comment: It can't be analysed using just `100` test samples. For sufficiently large samples and true random number generator this would work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import uniform

def pick_a_number_from_list(A):
    # picking an element from with the probability propotional to its 
    magnitude
 
    #Find the sum of the elements of List A
    sum=0
    for ele in A:
        sum+=ele
    #print(sum)

    #Normalizing the values using the sum
    D=[]
    for ele in A:
        d=ele/sum
        e=round(d,5)
        D.append(e)
    #print(D)

    #Cumulative Normalized Values
    C=[0]
    c=0
    for ele in D:
        c=c+ele
        f=round(c,5)
        C.append(f)
     #print(len(C))
     #print(C)

    #Find the Ramdom sampling by using uniform() between 0 to 1
    r=uniform(0.0,1.0)
    ran=round(r,5)
    #print(ran)

    # proportional Sampling 
    #number=0
    for i in range(len(C)-1):
        if(r>=C[i] and r <C[i+1]):
            #print(A[i])
            return A[i]
    #return number
    
def sampling_based_on_magnitued():
    A=[]
    n=int(input("Enter the length of List\n"))
    print("Enter the Elements between 1 to 100 in List A")
    for i in range(n):
        A.append(float(input()))
    print("The Elements in a List A are\n")
    print("A =",A)
    B=[]
    print("The Random Numbers generated between 1 to 100 are \n")
    for i in range(1,100):
         number = pick_a_number_from_list(A)
         B.append(number)
    print(B)
    #print(number)
    # To Print the Count of no of occurence of Number Ramdonly
    c=(sorted(A, reverse=True))
    print(c)
    for ele in c:
        print("count of {} is".format(ele),B.count(ele))     
sampling_based_on_magnitued()
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy has choice to an additional random function to account for probablity distribution. You should be using this.

```
from numpy.random import choice
draw = choice(list_of_candidates, number_of_items_to_pick,
              p=probability_distribution)
```

IN your case you can use

```
from numpy.random import choice

A = [0,5,27,6,13,28,100,45,10,79]
sumA=sum(A)
probability=[item/sumA for item in A]
for i in range(1,100):
    number = choice(A, 1, p=probability)
    print(number)
```

The number printed will be in probability distribution propotional to its magnitude. here the value 0 has 0 probability thoug but you can provide a better formula to calculate probability distribution if you want to give some probablity to zero

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of weights > 0, you can sample from a probability distribution according to those weights by mapping each weight to a sample from an exponential distribution, and then choosing the element with the lowest result. It is not possible to have an exponential distribution with parameter 0, but we can handle 0 by mapping to `math.inf`. This guarantees that the probabilities are proportional to the weights ([see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Distribution_of_the_minimum_of_exponential_random_variables)).

```py
import math
import random

def choose_with_weights(weights, lst=None):
    def sample(w):
        if w < 0:
            raise ValueError('Negative weight')
        elif w == 0:
            return math.inf
        else:
            return random.expovariate(w)

    _, min_i = min((sample(w), i) for i, w in enumerate(weights))
    return (lst or weights)[min_i]
```

If your weights can't include 0, then you can delete the `sample` helper function, and just use `random.expovariate` directly.

Examples, showing the resulting distributions via [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```py
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(choose_with_weights([1, 2, 3]) for i in range(60000))
Counter({3: 29812, 2: 20089, 1: 10099})
>>> Counter(choose_with_weights([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']) for i in range(60000))
Counter({'c': 30079, 'b': 20127, 'a': 9794})
```